# How to isolate page and div background colors in CSS?

Tags: css, colors

I am creating a login form but I could not get the BG color to work the way I wanted.

I want the page to have an overall background color of teal (`#00CEB9`). I created a form with a different background (let's just say red for demo), but the teal is still displayed inside the box.

[image: image with polluted BG]

I want the box to have 100% red background like this (while keeping the teal background on the rest of the page):

[image: image with isolated BG]

```
<div class="login-container">
  <form>
    <label for="login">Login</label>
    <input type="text" id="login">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="text" id="password">
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html *{
  background-color: #00CEB9;
}

.login-container {
    margin: 8px auto;
    border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
}
```

How can I keep my page background color and have a form box with its own background color without having them pollute each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your CSS from:

```
html *{
  background-color: #00CEB9;
}
```

to

```
html, body {
  background-color: #00CEB9;
}
```

By applying it to `html *` you're applying it to all elements that don't have a background colour already assigned.

See [CSS Selectors Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for more information on how to drill down on CSS selectors.

Answer (score 1):

`html *` means every element inside the html element, and this is not exactly exactly you are looking for.

You can use

```
html,  body {
    background-color: #00CEB9;
}
```

Instead

Answer (score 1):

Remove * from the first line of code in css. What * is doing is that it makes background color of everything  #00CEB9. That is why you are viewing the background color of form and every textbox as  #00CEB9. I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your css file. You are basically assigning background-color: teal to all the html elements because of the *.

Change the css to :

```
html {
  background-color: #00CEB9;
}
```